# recovering probability density from cumulative distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given a two-dimensional cumulative distribution

$$f(X<x,Y<y),$$
where $0<x,y<1$, how do I get a probability distribution of $x$, $P(x)$?

Is it simply
$$P(x) =  \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 dY\,f(X<x,Y<y)?$$

Answer (score 3):

It might be more usual  to start with the cumulative distribution function $$F_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y)= P(X \le x, Y \le y)$$
and then say that the marginal density for $X$ is $$f_X^{\,}(x)=\frac d {dx}F_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,+\infty)$$

If instead you start with a density $f_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y)$ where $F_{X,Y}^{\,}(x_0,y_0) =\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x_0}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{y_0} f_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) \, dy \,dx$ then you can say that the marginal density for $X$ is $$f_X^{\,}(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) \, dy$$

Comment: When you differentiate w.r.t. x don´t you get the pdf of $Y$? And what does $(x,+\infty)$ mean in this context?

Comment: @callculus : $F_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y)$ is a function of two variables.  $F_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,+\infty)$ is that with $y=+\infty$.  And no, differentiating with respect to $x$ does not give the marginal pdf for $Y$.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the reply.

Comment: I am confused about why $y\to \infty$ is needed. I indeed meant to write CDF when I wrote $f(X<x, Y<y)$ above. Since the domain is $0<x,y<1$, does this mean $f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_{X,Y}(x,1)$?

Comment: @Quantization The infinite limit is for the *general* case.  It works for any CDF in questions of this type.  However, for this *particular* exercise, $F_{\small X,Y}(x,\infty)=F_{\small X,Y}(x,1)$ holds..

Comment: Can I ask one more follow up question? What if I want to get a distribution

$f_X(x| a<y<b)$? i.e. probability distribution of $x$ for some given range of $y$ integrated.

Comment: I forget whether fundamental theorem of calculus applies for 2-dimensional case, i.e.
$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dy} F_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)$?